# Laravel Eloquent hasMany condition in parent table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

1. `places`

   - `id`
   - `name`
   - `address`
2. `users`

   - `id`
   - `name`
   - `email`
3. `reviews`

   - `id`
   - `place_id`
   - `user_id`
   - `title`
   - `review`
   - `as_anoniem`

The `user_id` is filled even if `as_anoniem` is `1`.

Now I want to have all the `reviews` for all the `places` with the `user` except for the ones with `as_anoniem = 1`.

Something like this:

```php
Place::with(['review' => function ($query) {
    return $query->with('user')->where('as_anoniem', 1);
}]);
```

This is not fully correct as it returns only `reviews` with `as_anoniem = 1`.

How can I achieve this using [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent)?

Comment: What! you have just changed the question right after I answerd, what is your question at all?

Comment: @TheAlpha, yes sorry to tell u that first. The first question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```php
$users = \App::User::with('reviews' => function($query) {
    $query->where('as_anoniem', '!=', 1);
})->get();
```

This will require you to create a `one-to-many` relationship in `App\User` model, for example:

```php
// App\User.php
public function reviews()
{
    // namespace: App\Review
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

Assumed that, the namespace for both `User` & `Review` is `App`, they are in the same directory.

### Update After the original question was changed by OP:

```php
$places = \App::Place::with('reviews' => function($query) {
    $query->with('user')->where('reviews.as_anoniem', '!=', 1);
})
->get();
```

Place Model:

```php
public function reviews()
{
    // namespace: App\Review
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

Review Model:

```php
public function user()
{
    // namespace: App\User
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: I've already answered your question but now you've changed the question, that's not right.

Comment: This doesn't work because it will give ONLY the reviews with as_anoniem=1. I want all the reviews but only the user of the reviews which don't have as_anoniem= 1.

Comment: This suppose to work because `as_anoniem` field is in the `reviews` table and I've used the right code as: `$query->with('user')->where('as_anoniem', '!=', 1);` so it should work, make sure you didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: the `where` applies to reviews so it won't show not show the anoniem reviews as all. Do you understand what i mean? sql will be something like `where as_anoniem != 1` but I want all the reviews.

Comment: Yes, I've done that exactly, `where('reviews.as_anoniem', '!=', 1)` means that gimme all the reviews with users where the `review.as_anoniem` is not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use values of model in conditions:

```php
class Content extends Model
{

    // ...

    /**
     * Get linked content
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function linked()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'source_content_id', 'source_content_id')
            ->where('source_content_type_id', '=', $this->source_content_type_id)
            ->where('id', '<>', $this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Such conditions don't work with eager loading

Comment: @AnatolySokolov is there any way we can use it with eager loading

Comment: @HamzaAfzal didn't met any of cases i should figure out yet (fortunately)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600698/16237933.

```php
class Game extends Eloquent {
    // many more stuff here

    // relation without any constraints ...works fine 
    public function videos() {
        return $this->hasMany('Video');
    }

    // results in a "problem", se examples below
    public function available_videos() {
        return $this->videos()->where('available','=', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in no way a good answer, as you are copy pasting code from one question to another one... in this case, just mark the original question as a duplicate. Still, it is not a duplicate... Just use author code instead of copying code out of context...