# Laravel pass parameters from controller to Model using 'With' clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, recursive-query

I am new in Laravel,
I want to pass the the $id from my controller in the model using with clause

My model

```
class Menucategory extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'parent_id', 'restaurant_id'];

  // loads only direct children - 1 level
  public function children()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Menucategory', 'parent_id');
  }

  // recursive, loads all descendants
  public function childrenRecursive()
  {
    return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
  }
}
```

My Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $menucatagories = Menucategory::with('childrenRecursive')->where('restaurant_id',$id)->where('parent_id','0')->get();
    return $menucatagories;
}
```

My current output is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "TestMenu Parant",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "restaurant_id": 12,
    "children_recursive": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "TestMenu SubCat1",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "restaurant_id": 12,
        "children_recursive": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "TestMenu other sub cat",
            "parent_id": 2,
            *******************
            "restaurant_id": 13,
            *******************
            "children_recursive": []
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "TestMenu other sub cat",
            "parent_id": 2,
            "restaurant_id": 12,
            "children_recursive": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "TestMenu SubCat2",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "restaurant_id": 12,
        "children_recursive": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I passed `$id=12` , but the problem is I get the values of others   `restaurant_id` in my child array, but if i use this it shows the correct `jSON`

```
public function childrenRecursive()
{
   $id=12;    
   return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive')->where('restaurant_id',$id);
}
```

my questions is how can i pass the $id from the controller to the model or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass your parameter in the controller itself using the following way.

```
     public function show($id)
     {
        $menucatagories =Menucategory::with(array('childrenRecursive'=>function($query) use ($id){
         $query->select()->where('restaurant_id',$id);
        }))
        ->where('restaurant_id',$id)->where('parent_id','0')->get();
        return $menucatagories;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `childrenRecursive` isn't wrong at all.

See here an simliar example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600698/2160816

So I think this should work

```
public function childrenRecursive($id = 12){
return $this->children()->where('restaurant_id',$id)->with('childrenRecursive');
}
```

Your Controller then could call

```
public function show($id)
{
    $menucatagories = Menucategory::where('parent_id','0')->childrenRecursive(12)->get();
    return $menucatagories;
}
```

I could not test it so may it won't work 100%