# Laravel 5 How to use parameters when calling a function in a view using Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, variables, foreach, parameters

I have a foreach in my view which displays tasks.

```
 @foreach($project_item->getVisibleTasks($tasklist->id) as $task)
```

And in my model I have the following function:

```
  public function getVisibleTasks($tasklist_id)
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'project_id')->where('tasklist_id', $tasklist_id)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
  }
```

The function does work when I delete the parameters. (But shows all the results. Because the where clause is deleted). When I pass a static number (for example 1) in my view, it still doesnt work.

How can I make this work?

Regards,

Dylan

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? Do you get an error or just no results?

Comment: @Bryan - No results.

Comment: Try passing the static number with a record you know exists and tagging on a `->get()` in the method call. for example `$project_item->getVisibleTasks(1)->get()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use a where clause when setting an eloquent relationship. The [Laravel Eloquent Relationship doc page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) doesn't say that is possible.

If possible use the code below where you rather use the eloquent query builder;

```
public function getVisibleTasks($tasklist_id){
    return App\Task::where('id',$this->project_id)->where('tasklist_id',$tasklist_id)->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I still can't call the function with the parameter from the view. The where clause it self does work. (When I use a static integer, it works). The problem is the foreach in the view. (I think its not possible to pass a parameter into a foreach?).

Comment: One option would be to call the function in the controller and pass the return list object to the view or you could use **@php** blade syntax to declare a variable in the view and assign the result of the function so that you only call the variable in the **@foreach** loop

Answer (score 0):

it may not be working because the relationship query is being called inside the relationship, you could create a relationship function and a query function, for example

```
public functon tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'project_id');
}
```

and then your function will be like this

```
public function getVisibleTasks($tasklist_id)
  {
    return $this->tasks()->where('tasklist_id', $tasklist_id)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
  }
```

that way laravel fetch the relationship and then filter it.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122568/laravel-pass-parameters-from-controller-to-model-using-with-clause/39122766#39122766)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This makes no difference. The issue with the parameter in the foreach still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd to me, it looks as though you are defining a relationship and running the query where the relationship is defined.  you should first define the relationship in the project_item model

```
 public function getVisibleTasks()
      {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'project_id');
      }
```

Also define the inverse of that relationship.

Then call it from your controller via

`$project_item ->getVisibleTasks()->orderBy('order', 'asc');`
this will automatically call the data that is related to your model.