# how to get table Attribute inside laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, model

I want get types only where wef is equal to current table wef. how to achieve this i am not able to get wef attribute with $this->attributes['wef']. Thanks in advance.

```
class Gst extends Model
    {
        //
        use Traits\UserAutoUpdate;
        protected $connection = 'mysql';
        protected $table = "gst";
        protected $fillable = ['name','wef'];

        public function types(){
           return $this->hasMany(GstType::class,'gst_id','id')->where('wef', $this->attributes['wef']);
        }   


    }
```

Error :
"Undefined index: wef"

Comment: I don't think ```$this->attributes['wef']``` will work. You need to pass the value in argument of ```types()``` function.

Comment: if you are using eager loading.. to get attributes just `$this->wef`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520209/how-to-access-model-hasmany-relation-with-where-condition

Comment: @Neha is it working?

Comment: @ZeroOne not showing error but returns empty array

Comment: as @DigitalDrifter answer.. better do like suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need a function that defines the relationship between GstType and Gst:

```
public function gstTypes()
{
     return $builder->hasMany(GstType::class,'gst_id','id');
}
```

Then make a scoped function:

```
public function scopeTypes($builder){
    return $builder->whereHas('gstTypes', function ($query) {
       $query->where('wef', $this->getAttribute('wef'));
   });
}
```

And use it like:

```
 $types = GstType::types();
```

Comment: The scope won't really work.  In most query contexts, you won't have any attributes available,  you'd have to fetch a model then query again on that model.  Doesn't really seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: Right, but where is the attribute 'wef' supposed to come from?