# Laravel Eloquent A good way to make relationship between country state and city table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, traits, laravel-8

I have 3 tables with schema like below

```
countries (rows: 250)
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| code       | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI |         |                |country code
| phone_code | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| region     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| subregion  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
states (rows: 4866)
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| country_code| varchar(255)        | NO   | MUL |         |                | this is country code
| state_code  | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| lat         | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| lon         | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+    
cities (rows: 146068)
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| lat        | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| lng        | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| population | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |                |
| state_code | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |state code not unique
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp           | YES  |     |         |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am using quickadminpanel to generate these CRUD but the main issue is i imported these from a csv files
[git link for csv](https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database) and csvimport trait like https://pastebin.com/G9z8Rjf1

is there any way i can build relationship between these three tables using
`country:code and state:country_code` relationship and `state:state_code and city:state_code`
relationship because i cannot add states (rows: 4866) and cities (rows: 146068) manually

so how can i form relationship using models or any better way or any better trait for making relationship?

Comment: Why wouldnt you use the primary key as a reference key to another table?

Comment: You can use the primary key of country table is the foreign keys of other tables,, and if you  want to retrieve also the country code with each record then you can simply use `with ()` function

Comment: thats what i want to do but to do that the `code` and `country_code` column should match  and make a relationship using a model or using db it doesent matter

Comment: how do i match it with different table i got good example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57358462/15121609 but here he has search query but i have a column in both table any way to get that ?

Comment: You can simply just change the primary key from id to code

Comment: Ok lets say i have country_code something like `select * from countries , states where countries.code = "IN" AND countries.code = states.country_code` this is the raw sql i come up with dont know if its wrong or not but it should be like this i think

Comment: for country i can change primary key to code since its unique but i cant say for state and city since state code is repeated between countries but not in a country

Comment: yeah thats correct.. you can set code as primary in countries table and coutry_code as foreign key in both state and city(repeatable) and state_code In state will be unique in state tables well as city code will be unique in city table..Have you got the point? right>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Change The Primary Keys of each table to code,state_code,city_code Respectively**

NB:**change multiple to unique  the state_code in states table and city_code in cities table**

And In your Models change The Relationship like

*`/* return $this->hasMany(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`**

```
return $this->hasMany(State::class, 'country_code', 'code');
```

And

/// return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');///

```
return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'code', 'country_code');
```

then You can access all data like normal..

Comment: i got an issue i cannot create a primary key of `state_code` column in both table since its not unique any way for that ?
it just says plz select primary key or unique key

Comment: U are storing States names in state table right so? state code will be unique in states table ...(it will be the foreign key in city table because a state have many cities..).
a state doesn't have many state code.. just like a key.. it will be unique.

Comment: change the state_code and city_code to unique in state table and city table respectively

Comment: state code is not unique because its repeated  because of different country using same state code :(

Comment: in that table state code MH for Maharashtra ( which is in India) is also code for  County Meath which is in Ireland and many more like this example with same state code

Comment: @RohitMahajan Okay. There is 2 ways 1. Have to add an extra column to every table to relate this data. 2. Just keep state_code as Unique..
i prefer 2nd method since  its related to real-life example( a pincode,a state code,a country code) cant be repeated. its only belongs to one state/city/country

Comment: it seems country code is not unique between country but is unique for a country https://ibb.co/QFg8r0m check this so if thats the case the option 2 is out

Comment: https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/blob/master/csv/states.csv search for ur state and then use same state code see if it matches for my case it matches atleast 5 countries using same code :(

Comment: i will try to make a table with relation between each country , state and city let me try that option 1 use different table to relate the data

Comment: Yeah just add and extra column and set its  default value as same as index value of country table index value(value of id)

Comment: i created a pivot table for the same it should work now thanks